# How to analyze $\{|f(z)|\le M\}$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

> Given a continuously differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^2}$. If $\{x : \det Jf(x)=0 \}$ is finite, and for each positive constant $M$,  $\{z\in \mathbb{R^2} :|f(z)|\le M\}$ is bounded. Prove that $f$ is surjective.

**My attempt**

I wanted to prove that $ f(\mathbb{R^2})$ is open and closed. In order to do this I proved that $f(\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{x : \det Jf(x)=0 \})$ is open. I wanted to prove then that $f(\mathbb{R^2})$ is closed. But I got stuck on how to use the condition that $\{z\in \mathbb{R^2} :|f(z)|\le M\}$ is bounded.

Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does $J$ denote the Jacobian?

Comment: @YiFan Yes, $Jf(x)$ is the Jacobian matrix at $x$

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share an answer to my own question now.

*Proof :*

> 1. $f(\mathbb{R^2})$ is closed.

Given $y^0\in  \overline{f(\mathbb{R^2})}$. Then there exists a sequence of points $\{ y^k=f(x^k)\}_{k\ge1}$ convergent to $y^0$. Then via the condition of boundness we know $(x^k)$ is bounded, and hence there exists a subsequence $(x^{n_k})$ convergent to some point, say $x^0$. Then we know form the continuity that $\lim_{k\to \infty} f(x^{n_k})=f(x^0)$, which implies that $y^0=f(x^0)$. Thus $f(\mathbb{R^2})$ is closed.

> 2. $f(\mathbb{R^2}\setminus \{x:\det Jf(x)=0\})$ is open.

Just note that $\{x:\det Jf(x)=0\}$is a finite set, and hence $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus \{x:\det Jf(x)=0\}$ is open. Then via inverse function theorem we know  $f(\mathbb{R^2}\setminus \{x:\det Jf(x)=0\})$ is open.

> 3. $f$ is surjective

Suppose for contradiction that $f$ is not surjective. Thus $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus f(\mathbb{R^2})$ and $f(\mathbb{R^2}\setminus \{x:\det Jf(x)=0\})$ are two nonempty open sets in the union of them, which is derived by removing finitely many points in $\mathbb{R^2}$. That is a contradiction, since the topopogy space derived by removing finitely many points in $\mathbb{R^2}$ is connected.